# Reflection in geometry

Tags: geometry

I got a) but do not know how to show part b) and the rest[image]

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward solution: The set of points $v$ that are fixed satisfies the equation
$$f(v) = v$$
or, since you can write $f(v) = Mv$ for the matrix $M$ given in the problem,
$$Mv = v.$$

Solve this system of two equations using substitution, or Gaussian elimination. You will see that the system is degenerate, with a one-parameter family of solutions. Check that this family describes points on a line.

Slightly sneakier solution: the fixed points satisfy $$(M-I)v = 0.$$

In other words, the fixed points are the vectors in the kernel (null space) of $M-I$. The rank of $M-I$ is clearly not zero, and clearly not 2 since $\det (M-I) = 0$, so it must be 1. The kernel is thus a one-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is a line through the origin.

However, since you will need an explicit equation for the line in parts c and d, you might as well compute it using the straightforward solution.